# How do I see which windows updates failed to install if what was said was installing cannot be seen?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

My computer was installing windows updates today in full screen after restarting my computer, or at least it says it was.

[image: windows update installing configuring on full screen restart]

Afterwards when using Windows I looked at "view update history" in the windows update screen of settings, I saw an update with today's date that failed to install. After closing the window and opening it again, this failed update disappeared.

[image: view update history windows 10]

So if windows update ran when I restarted my computer with the "windows update is installing do not turn off your computer", where is this windows update to be seen?

**Update:** Also I just installed a different windows update to the one mentioned earlier, that doesn't appear in my update history, so where is it?

Comment: It should be displayed in your screenshot (Windows Updates History).  There are commands that could be ran but it pulls from the same location.

Comment: Also,  try restarting again. Let it sit running for 30 minutes (to let it install updates if some are to be updated). Restart, allow to run 10 minutes after restarting. Then check update history again.

Comment: Get-WUIsPendingReboot should display pending updates, but I suspect, a good old reboot is necessary

Comment: "Ran different update"   Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator,  dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /startcomponentcleanup  then  dism.exe  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth  then SFC /SCANNOW   Complete, restart, run Windows Update again.

Comment: Running `Get-WUIsPendingReboot` gives me a `provider load failure` error.

Comment: There's a typo, you missed out `/online`. You meant to say `DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth`

Comment: I tried all the suggestions here and they don't work.

Comment: Your going to have to reset Windows Update.  This of course will make it impossible but the module I suggested should have returned something instead of an error.  Your screenshot indicates you have not installed a single Windows update since October.  When you ran the commands in the answer below you did that

Comment: [Here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Reset-Windows-Update-Agent-d824badc) is a full script to flush and reset Windows Update.  Since I suspect the data required to determine what the last update no longer exists, you might as well try it to correct the core problem of not receiving updates to Windows for 3 months.

Comment: I have had updates install since october. This month in january I had Malicious Software Removal Tool installed, and updates for realtek and intel drivers. The feature update you see in the screenshot has a new version released every 6 months, so the next release is in April.

Comment: If I reset the windows update components then the `SoftwareDistribution` folder will be deleted, so the log of which windows updates were previously installed, will be deleted. So it will be impossible for me to see which windows updates I have already installed, it'll just be blank, making the problem worse.

Comment: A month later it looks like all the windows updates required to install, eventually got installed. What changes happened between now and then to fix it knowing I didn't do anything, I don't think will be discovered.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, this is a PowerShell script, first, to open PowerShell:

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>>>type `PowerShell`>><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Then, once you are in PowerShell, paste this line of code:

```powershell
(Get-WindowsPackage -Online | Where {$_.PackageState -match "Staged|InstallPending"}).PackageName
```

It will display the packagenames of all pending Windows update packages.

You can try this:

```powershell
Get-WindowsPackage -Online
```

To get all Windows update packages present in your computer;

This:

```powershell
Get-WindowsPackage -Online | Where {$_.PackageState -match "Staged|InstallPending"}
```

To get all information available about the pending updates.

You can then narrow down the list further by installation date:

```powershell
Get-WindowsPackage -Online | Where {$_.PackageState -match "Staged|InstallPending"} | Where {$_.InstallTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") -eq "2021-01-16"}
```

The added criterion will return only the packages installed on a date whose yyyy-MM-dd expression equals to the given date string. The example I had given is the date of today (the current present day), change the date to the date when your computer tried to install the update and failed.

You can get rid of it by:

```powershell
$packagename=(Get-WindowsPackage -Online | Where {$_.PackageState -match "Staged|InstallPending"} | Where {$_.InstallTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") -eq "2021-01-16"}).packagename
dism /Online /Remove-Package /PackageName:$packagename /norestart
```

You then need to run the following commands to prevent Windows from trying to install this update again:

```powershell
net stop wuauserv
remove-item "$env:windir\SoftwareDistribution\Download" -force -recurse
net start wuauserv
dism /online /cleanup-image /revertpendingactions
dism /online /cleanup-image /startcomponentcleanup
```

I hope you find the answer useful; Best regards.

---

Get-WindowsPackage is a cmdlet provided by dism, basically `Get-WindowsPackage -Online` does the same thing as `dism /online /get-packages`, the difference being Get-WindowsPackage is a cmdlet, it returns structured result which can be used for other cmdlets.

If `Get-WindowsPackage -Online` doesn't list all your installed updates, then I think no third-party software can list all your installed updates, as they are all based on dism.

And if you aren't seeing any pending updates, then there must be something wrong, your update failed to install, so it should be pending install.

---

If all suggestions failed to solve this particular problem for you, then I can give you one more advice: as a last resort, you have to reinstall Windows. Windows 10 .iso files are free to download now, you can download it and perform a repair install, you can keep all your files and your system will be fixed in this way; Beware it can't fix corrupt user profiles though, you have to perform a clean install and create a new profile if user profile is corrupted.

Comment: `Get-WindowsPackage -Online` does not show all the windows updates installed on my computer.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it doesn't work. Also I have no pending windows update packages.

Comment: If you ran the commands in this answer then you deleted the information necessary to answer your question. **remove-item "$env:windir\SoftwareDistribution\Download" -force -recurse** this folder contained that information.  Be sure you reboot after you did that

Comment: I did not run the `/Remove-Package` command as deleting windows updates that were already installed would have been counterproductive. I missed out that step.